# Log-in only once using wget multiple times on same ftp-server

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, wget

Basically, I am using wget on a file containing multiple URLs. I notice that for each line the command I use:

`wget -i list_of_urls`

and for each row in "list_of_urls" wget does a log-in step to the FTP server that I'm downloading from. It does the log-in step automatically, without me entering any username and password. Each line produces the output

```
Connecting to ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov (ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov)|130.14.250.13|.21... connected. 
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
```

followed by the file downloading.

Is there any way to log in only for the first row and then using that login to download all the following rows? Since the URLs point to the same FTP server, only different files, it feels like logging in for each row is wasteful.

Edit: changed from "website" to "FTP server" since that was what I actually meant, thanks. Added a sample output of the log-in message.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: When you manually download multiple files from this website, does it require a login only once? Does the server redirect you to an URL that includes some session ID as a parameter or does it set cookies? I think `wget` in a single run should handle cookies, but your list of URLs might not work with a session ID embedded in the URL, e.g. something like `http://server.some.domain/path/to/file?session=1234ABCD`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl You are right, I overlooked the `ftp` tag, and the question states "the URLs point to the same *website*". This should be changed to "the URLs point to the same *FTP server*"

Comment: You are both right, it is ftp that is used. I edited my answer and also added a sample output of the log-in message.

Comment: You might want to use a tool like [tag:lftp] that is more scriptable.

Comment: Are you in the mind that it's wasteful because the files are downloaded in serial (ie one at a time) and therefore takes longer than it should?  If you wanted to run wget multiple times at once you could use a loop and background the operation.  Something like:

`for url in $(< list_of_urls); do wget "$url" & done`

Comment: Yes, like @MartinPrikryl said my main issue is that a new connection is established for each file. I tried using rsync protocol instead of ftp since the file provider also supported that. Rsync seemed to work in the fashion that only one connection had to be established, and the downloads using rsync went much faster! I still don't know how to do it with wget, but using rsync instead seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling around I think using the rsync protocol solved the problem. This works in this case since the file host has both ftp and rsync servers containing the same files. I then simply (for small file sizes) use

`rsync $(tr '\n' ' ' <list_of_urls) /usrpath/`

which was much faster than using wget on the ftps. I had to include the `$(tr '\n' ' ' <list_of_urls)` since the list of urls had end of line separation, but rsync takes space-separated files in the command line. It seems like the rsync protocol in this case only logs on once and then downloads all files, since it went much faster.

Another problem arises with this method when list_of_urls is very long, which I haven't solved yet.